# UIImagepickercontrollerreferenceurl returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

After picking image from camera this method gets called.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

//    cameraImage.image = [info objectForKey:
//                         UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

NSLog(@"%@",info);

NSURL *url = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSLog(@"%@",[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]);
}
```

I get the image from UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage. But UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL returns nil. I do not know what am i doing wrong. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no Reference URL because the photo does not exist on the file system until you actually save it.

MediaURL is only used for movies. It is the URL for the compressed version of the movie, saved on a temp folder, accessible by your application.

Comment: you are saying why it is ill, but not mentioning how we can get rid of it? can you help pls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for getting the file name for chosen photos. For newly taken pictures UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL would return nil since NSURL does not exist so i assign a default name. It referenceUrl exists i get the filename with help of PHImageManager which was introduced in Photos Framework.

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.selectedIndex = 1
    var fileName = UIImage.defaultFileName()

    //Pic is comming from library so url exists
    if let referenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL, image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage  {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let phAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceUrl], options: nil).lastObject as! PHAsset
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(phAsset, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in
                if info!.keys.contains(NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")) {
                    let path = info![NSString(string: "PHImageFileURLKey")] as! NSURL
                    fileName = path.lastPathComponent!
                }
                self.addDocumentDelegate?.tabBarControllerDidTakePicture(self, image: image, fileName: fileName)
                AppRoot.sharedInstance.dismissModalViewController(true, completion: nil)
            })
        } else {
            self.addDocumentDelegate?.tabBarControllerDidTakePicture(self, image: image, fileName: fileName)
            AppRoot.sharedInstance.dismissModalViewController(true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage { //Pic is comming from Camera so url does not exists
        self.addDocumentDelegate?.tabBarControllerDidTakePicture(self, image: image, fileName: fileName)
        AppRoot.sharedInstance.dismissModalViewController(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```